# How to infinitely loop over an array in React render?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using [typist](https://github.com/jstejada/react-typist) to type different words from an array in the same position and I'd like to infinitely loop over the array. That is once I've gone over the array once I'd like to start again.

I've created a component that renders the typing functionality the way I'd like it to however it runs once and as I'm relatively new to JS and React I can't quite find a way to rerender on loop in a way that doesn't throw an console error. Here's my component which is used in the main components render:

```
    const typeRender = 
        Tags.map((tag) => {
            const arrLen = Tags.length - 1
            if (Tags.indexOf(tag) != arrLen) {
                return [ <h2 className='skillname' key={tag.id}>{tag.value}</h2>,
                         <Typist.Backspace count={tag.value.length} delay={500} />]
            }
            else {

                return [<h2 className='skillname' key={tag.id}>{tag.value}</h2>,
                <Typist.Backspace count={tag.value.length} delay={500} />]

            }
        })
```

Tags is the array of objects that I'm iterating over, and in the main component render this is all wrapped in a Typist component.

Any suggestions on how I might implement this, I'm using hooks, so I thought maybe useEffect might be something I could use here.

Comment: Generally, an infinite `useEffect` loop is a bug. Are you looking for something like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: Why not just make typeRender a function and use recursion to return the function within itself?

`typeRender = () => {*your code here*}` then inside that function put `return typeRender`

Comment: It's more so that I want to figure out a way in the main render to reset typeRender once it has reached the last element of the array. With Typist you can declare the delay which may change in theory if I decide to change the speed, so would something like a `setTimeout` be a bit restrictive in this regard?

Comment: `setTimeout` could be exactly what you need actually because it calls a callback function after a delay, if you had a recursive callback that could give you the functionality you want (i.e. wrap the `setTimeout`in another function, and then the callback function of `setTimeout` can call that function/itself)

Comment: @SC1988 thanks, I'll look up a few ways of implementing that now and see how I get on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @darcycp no worries let me know how it turns out